# Android setContentView suppressed by AsyncTask in onCreate

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sqliteopenhelper, setcontentview

I want to show some message and a progress bar while my app initializes.

I need to insert some dictionaries of words into a SQLite database the first time my app is run. To do this I have an AsyncTask which opens my SQLiteOpenHelper and closes it again, just so the database initialization is done once.

```
private class AsyncDbInit extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private Context context;
    private Intent intent;

    public AsyncDbInit(Context context, Intent intent){
        this.context = context;
        this.intent = intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this.context);
        db.close();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
        context.startActivity(this.intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... params) {}
}
```

This AsyncTask is called in my onCreate() method, but I've also tried to run it from onStart() and onResume() without succes.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dispatcher);

    ... //some code finding the right intent

    new AsyncDbInit(this, nextIntent).execute();
}
```

Somehow this last line, which calls the AsyncTask, stops my UI from showing up; the screen just stays blank until the AsyncTask is completed and the new activity is started.
When I comment that line out, the UI shows up just fine.

The only thing I can come up with is that the SQLiteOpenHelper somehow blocks the UiThread, but I couldn't find anything about that either.

Answer (score 0):

In the AsyncTask we have some methods. Just like in doInBackground() we do the things  we wants to be done in the background and there are two methods also whch are onPreExecute() and onPostExecute(). Create and progress dialog and show the dialog in onPreExecute() method and dismiss it in onPostExecute() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using AsynTask.executeOnExecutor() with the thread pool executor. If this works, it means something involved with loading your UI is also using an AsyncTask. AsyncTasks by default run sequentially on a single work thread and this can introduce contention. This serial execution **is often what you want**, but not always.

Does you UI use any libraries to load strings or other content? Can you provide your layout XML?

Comment: I have tried the executeOnExecutor() with the thread pool executor, but it didn't work. Still the same UI freezing.
I now start the AsyncTask with a button. The view now loads but a few seconds after pressing the button my screen turns black until the AsyncTask is done.